# How to get started on a Simple Physics based game (with angle/power)?

Tags: java, flash, game-engine, game-physics

[image]

Basically there will be a club and a ball. You can control the power and angle to hit the ball.

How do I go about implementing this? Is flash the easiest way to go? I want to implement this as a facebook game. Any game libraries specific to this I can use to quickly implement a basic version? I am comfortable with Java and PHP.

Comment: You may also want to look into JavaScript (which isn't really related to Java), especially in the context of web games/facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Yah there's lots of options but in this case picking an overall technology based on your expected user base is probably a good plan.  If you expect lots of mobile users (check statistics to get an idea of people using Facebook on mobile for games) then Flash is not the way to go (and I'm a Flex guy).  However if you're going for the desktop market Flash in my experience is easier to use than some amalgamation of JavaScript libraries.  If you do choose to go the JavaScript route, I'd suggest exploring some existing frameworks like Processing.js to handle all the nitty gritty drawing and keep you focused on the high level stuff.  Depending on what technology you pick the choice for a physics library will follow, this shouldn't be too much of a concern as you're not trying to do rocket science here, simple Newtonian physics will do.  If you're a fan of physics it might be worth it to just write the stuff yourself but if you want some more complex interactions check out things like Box2D or other physics engines.  The problem with using one of those is the learning curve to understand how to use their set of objects, with real simple stuff if you're not frightened by some math and physics it's probably worth it to do it yourself.  I have a couple of other stack overflow obligations to get back to before I could legitimately help you out but if you have some questions about how to solve the problems you need to solve feel free to ask (if google can't easily answer them for you).